# loading an html partial view with jquery get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to load an html partial view in a div using Jquery and a Get method (i don't want a post).
But i have an error  "JsonRequestBehavior" need AllowGet.

I don't understand this error because my dataType is html not json.
fiddler show a header with "Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01".

How can i load my partial view ?

my html

```
<div id="view" class="box">
</div>
<button id="button" type="button">Next ></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'html',
                url: "/declarations/ValiderHeures/1234/15-06-2013/",
                sucess: function (result) {
                    alert('ok');
                    // replace html div
                }
            });
);
</script>
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult ValiderHeures(Int32 id, DateTime date)
{
   FaireUneDeclarationViewModel vm = new FaireUneDeclarationViewModel();
   vm.Load(User.Identity.Name, this.UserId.Value);
   return (vm);        
}
```

I have found my problem:

Thanks , i have found my error:

in my base controller i have:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
....
filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = new GenericJsonResult() { Message = filterContext.Exception.Message == null ? "Une erreur a été détectée !" : filterContext.Exception.Message, Error = true } };
....
}
}
```

the error is in the wiew, and my base controller errorException return a Json result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it make any difference if you do;

```
 return PartialView("View", vm);
```

Comment: a litle mistake in my post. I' am already return PartialView("ViewMane",vm);